# R Graphics Legends Commands

Tags: r

Instead of $a,b,c$ in the following command suppose we want to write mathematical notation $\delta_{a}, \mu_{b},\gamma_{c}$. What should be the correct command for this? Please answer.
legend=c("a","b","c")

Comment: Did you look at any of [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+greek)? Please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expression`

```
plot(0)
legend(x = "topleft", legend = expression(alpha[a], mu[b], gamma[c]))
```

[image]